# Execute Javascript function on each "activity"

Tags: jsf, primefaces

So my JBoss has a session inactivity timer of 60 minutes, so the user gets logged out after an hour without activity.

I want to display a countdown that resets on each "activity", but what exactly counts as activity and how can I couple my JS function to any such activity?

We're using JBoss 7.2 and a Primefaces/JSF web application.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/idleMonitor.xhtml

Comment: It seems that the "active" Ajax event gets triggered by keystrokes, mouse movements, ... but those are not activities that reset the JBoss inactivity timer unfortunately.

Comment: Use `<p:ajax event="active" listener="#{...}" />` to send activity to the backend